# Node.js, sequelize. The script execution is not stopped

Tags: node.js, callback

The following script is not finished after the execution. DB got the record but the script is continue working. Why?

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'mylogin', 'mypassword', {
                host: 'db_host',
                port: 5432,
                dialect: 'postgres',
                protocol: 'postgres',
                logging: true,
                omitNull: true,
});

var iteration = sequelize.define('iteration', {
               id: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT ,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true},
    imported: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
    }, {
tableName: 'iterations'}
);

iteration.create({ imported: Sequelize.NOW}).success(function(iter) {
console.log(iter);
});
```

Comment: You could always force it to exit with `process.exit()` if you're feeling desperate.

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I have generated the exception to break script before it

Answer (score 5):

You must call sequelize.close() in order to stop the execution.
As long as the connection is open the execution does not stop.